# Что лучше использовать Ofstream\ifstream или fstream и указывать параметры?

Tags: c++, файлы

В c++ есть и то и то, но что лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если читать - `ifstream`, если писать - `ofstream`.

Если и то, и другое - `fstream`...